# Is there a way to remove all formatting from a tag - and apply whatever style is already "in force"?

Tags: html, css, overriding, inline

I want to add a tag (in this case, h2) to some text - but I want to remove all style formatting associated with that tag.

```
<div>
  <nav>
    <h2>Menu 1</h2>
    <h2>Menu 2</h2>
  </nav>
<div>
```

So I want the menu items to have whatever formatting is already setup from my theme's css - without applying any of the formatting associated with the h2.  But I don't want to "hardcode" the formatting - otherwise I'd have to either make a special nav.h2 css entry, and change it every time I change my theme.

Is there anything like a "style=ForgetEverythingDefinedForThisTagAndUseParentStyles:true;" option? Or my only choice is to "hardcode" the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I believe this to be poor practice, as you should be designing your styles so that you do not have to go back and 'hardcode' a 'reset' but in this case you would want to do something similar to below:

.css

```
.inheritall {
all:inherit
}
```

.html

```
<div>
  <nav>
    <h2 class="inheritall">Menu 1</h2>
    <h2>Menu 2</h2>
  </nav>
<div>
```

For further reference please view: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: Thank you - just what I was looking for!